# Mongodb Upgrade issue

Tags: linux, mongodb

I have upgraded my MONGODB version from 2.6.7 to 3.0.3.

When I run following command

```
./mongod --dbpath database --storageEngine wiredTiger
```

getting output,

```
2015-10-19T14:47:04.936+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=22642 port=27017 dbpath=database 64-bit host=inkilab-Vostro-2520
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.0
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: a841fd6394365954886924a35076691b4d149168
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-179-177-12 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-10-19T14:47:04.937+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "database", engine: "wiredTiger" } }
2015-10-19T14:47:04.963+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten] listen(): bind() failed errno:98 Address already in use for socket: 0.0.0.0:27017
2015-10-19T14:47:04.963+0530 E NETWORK  [initandlisten]   addr already in use
2015-10-19T14:47:05.203+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=1G,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_max=4),statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),checkpoint=(wait=60,log_size=2GB),statistics_log=(wait=0),
2015-10-19T14:47:27.542+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2015-10-19T14:47:27.543+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2015-10-19T14:47:27.543+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2015-10-19T14:47:27.543+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close sockets...
2015-10-19T14:47:27.600+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2015-10-19T14:47:49.491+0530 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2015-10-19T14:47:49.518+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 48
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bindIp error indicates you already have a service running on the default port. In order to override, you must first stop or delete the service and start the mongod again.

In order to kill the services on the default port, you can try the following commands:

```
ps -eAf | grep mongo
```

This will give you current instances, if any of any service by name like "mongo", or interpret as service like 'mongo%'. Now you will have to kill the traces you have on the default port and this can be done using the kill command in shell. For help type:

```
man kill
```

Alternatively, you can start mongod on a new assigned port by using the -p or --port switch